# How to define class with properties and its data type dynamically in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

For e.g. I have following class, with interface ProjectAttrs.

```
export class ProjectAttrsImpl implements ProjectAttrs {
    name: string;
    description: string | null;
    coordinates: string | null;   
}
```

I have too many classes in JSON implementation so trying to define all classes dynamically.
I got following structure from JSON parse

```
 project: {
   name: 'string',
   description: 'string | null',
   coordinates: 'string | null',
  }
```

but its properties like name and description are taking value as string. I want to define its data-type as string not value. Please help

Comment: This is only possible if the JSON's type is known statically.

Comment: ^ Adding on to above [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVZlGN) is a way to do it.

Comment: totally my bad.Its not JSON implementation. I have yaml file with me and loaded it witj js-yaml package. So after loading I am getting following structure of class and from that I have to define class Project
{
  id: { type: 'uuid' },
  attributes: {
    name: { description: 'The name of this project.', type: 'string' },
    description: {
      description: 'The description of this project.',
      type: 'string | null',
      nullable: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      description: 'The location of this project.',
      type: 'string | null',
      nullable: true
    },

Answer (score 0):

Parsing **from** typescript **to** JSON is not possible, it will not make an interface. A JSON file is just some text with a few primitives, including boolean, number, string and null.

A JSON parser is used **from** JSON **to** typescript to generate an interface based on the JSON provided.

Comment: It actually is possible in the way they want if the JSON's data is known statically, and it can be done in someway like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVZlGN).

Comment: That's still **from** JSON **to** typescript.

Comment: I believe they *want* from JSON to real TypeScript types? Am I reading the question wrong? Even still it's possible to reverse my example implementation from types to JSON (then I guess... copy and paste the type into a JSON file lol).

Comment: I think you are, look at what he says : "I got following structure from JSON parse" : *he tried to parse his typescript to make a JSON class or something along those lines*

Comment: What? `JSON.parse` implies that they are trying to parse a string into an object. Then they are trying to convert the object into types they can use.

Comment: They must use a VSCode library like [this one](https://github.com/quicktype/quicktype), but yeah, I'm as baffled as you ...

Comment: @kellys your solution is working but I need that properties to be write also as in I can assign values to it. Currently getting readonly as json is declared as const.
how to make read and write on the properties ? Thanks for solution. Getting difficulty in understanding 'infer' and GetRealType type